# Login timeout expired

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, connectivity

I am using a program that is connected to SQL Server. The program has started giving 'login timeout expired' errors.

If I login to SSMS and query the database the program connects and it fails again when I close SSMS.

What could cause this?

Answer (score 0):

*Troubleshooting: Timeout Expired*
A list of Typical Causes of this problem can be found [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190181(v=sql.105).aspx)
Additional tips [here](https://kb.iu.edu/d/aytk)

Hard to tell what can be causing this with no details, there's a number of approaches you can try each one depending on a different scenario.